# How to display content in image::before and image::after properly for all browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser, icons, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I'm using following code 
**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="x-grid-cell" style="width:35px;">
        <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-action-col" style="text-align:left;">
            <img role="button" alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-grid-notecolumn x-grid-notecolumn-unchecked">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

with some CSS Pseudo Classes for the image tag inside. See [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fqdeoe54/).
Why do my Icons not appear in IE and Firefox but only in Chrome. What should I do for cross-browser, what exactly is the bad markup? **I cannot change the HTML markup.**

Comment: Images can't have pseudo-elements.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't read the specs. Unfortunately it is not specified yet.